# Html.Action() causes The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, braintree, antiforgerytoken

In the same page, I have 2 forms. One is a simple newsletter subscription, the other is a Braintree "Drop-in" payment form.

When I submit the Braintree form, after the form submission I get a `The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present` exception **while reloading the page**, relatively to the newsletter form.

This is really weird, considering that the newsletter form works perfectly, and I see no reason why the submission of one form should generate such exception in the other, especially when reloading the page instead of on POST.

This is the code of the newsletter form, which is contained in a PartialView:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubscribeForm", "Components"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    // other inputs omitted for brevity
}
```

I render it in the footer using `@Html.Action("SubscribeForm", "Components")`. This is the ComponentsController, with the GET and POST actions:

```
 public ActionResult SubscribeForm()
 {
     // do stuff
     return PartialView("_SubscribeForm", viewModel);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult SubscribeForm(SubscribeViewModel model)
 {
     // do stuff
 }
```

And this is the exception:

[image]

Any idea what could trigger such behaviour?

Comment: This may be related to he fact that `@Html.Action()` will call the POST method rather than the GET method if the current request is a POST. Can you show the signatures of the controller methods including the attributes

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. I updated my question to include the code of the ComponentsController that handles the "SubscribeForm" Action.

Comment: OK, Can you test this by changing the POST method to say `public ActionResult Subscribe(SubscribeViewModel model)` and adjust the form to `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Components"))` to match.

Comment: Omg you're right... well spotted indeed. Because the POST and GET actions have the same name, Html.Action in this case was calling the POST. I was assuming it would always take the GET... Thank you so much.

Comment: Normally its fine (and preferred) to have the same name, but its just an unfortunate issue when using `@Html.Action()`

Answer (score -3):

You must post your form in which the verification token is present. For this, consider using a submit button/input tag.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SubscribeForm", "Components")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" /> }
```

Comment: `@Html.Action()` DOES NOT generate a link - it call a server method and renders its result.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with a submit button.